# I am currently solving a problem for my class on Plancks blackbody function

Tags: python

```
    import math
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
hc=1.23984186E3

k=1.3806503E-23

T=(np.linspace(5000,10000,50))

lamb = np.linspace(0.00001,.0000001,50)
print(len(lamb))
print (len(T))

planck_top=8*math.pi*hc
planck_bottom1=lamb*1000000
planck_bottom2=math.exp(hc//lamb*k*T)
planck=planck_top//planck_bottom
```

I keep getting this error here;

```
>
planck_bottom2=math.exp(hc//lamb*k*T)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am not sure how to correct this, as we are dealing with a large array here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hc//lamb*k*T` returns an array, and `math.exp()` can work with a number only. So, the following would work:

```
planck_bottom2=[math.exp(i) for i in hc//lamb*k*T]
```

It returns a list containing each number in the array `hc//lamb*k*T` correspondingly exponentiated.

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have another option of using `numpy` instead of `math`.

## Using Numpy for Array Calculations

Just replace **`math`** by **`np`** since you already `import numpy as np`.

```py
planck_top=8*np.pi*hc
planck_bottom2 = np.exp(hc//lamb*k*T)
```

### About using `math` and/or `numpy`:

As an additional piece of information, I encourage you to look at the following references for evaluating when/if you should choose `math` and/or `numpy`.

1. [What is the difference between import numpy and import math [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648058/what-is-the-difference-between-import-numpy-and-import-math?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Are NumPy's math functions faster than Python's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650194/are-numpys-math-functions-faster-than-pythons)
3. ["Math module functions cannot be used directly on ndarrays because they only accept scalar, not array arguments."](http://kestrel.nmt.edu/~raymond/software/python_notes/paper003.html)